# C# ASP Confirm Pop Up (Again)

Tags: c#, asp.net, confirm

I looked around in several forums for an answer to my problem, but I only found the solution in combination with a button.

I have to "translate" a website from Javascript to C# ASP because I have to store data in a SQL DB.

Now, I had a validation routine were the entries were checked before the data as sent by mail (that was in the old website, now it should be stored). One of the checks was only a warning (confirm) and not an error (alert). In JavaScript I did this with:

```
     if (a > b){
    Check = confirm("Are you sure your entry is correct?");;
    if (Check == false){
       return false;
       }
    }
```

Since I have many more checks before and after this part, I can't hook it to a button.

Is there a way to solve it like the alert? e. g.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
<asp:Literal id="ltlAlert" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">    </asp:Literal> 
</script>

   private void Say(string Message)
{
    // Format string properly 
    Message = Message.Replace("'", "\\'");
    Message = Message.Replace(Convert.ToChar(10).ToString(), "\\n");
    Message = Message.Replace(Convert.ToChar(13).ToString(), "");
    //Display as JavaScript alert (!)
    ltlAlert.Text = "alert('" + Message + "')";
}
```

like:

```
private bool Ask(string Message)
{
    // Code to display confirm from Javascript here
    return;
}
```

I'm pretty new to C# (otherwise I programmed in VB, VBA and - Long ago - in COBOL) so I'm still trying to get my bearings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following where you can check several conditions before submitting a form?  The button would call that JavaScript function.

```
function ValidateForm(){
    if(email is invalid){
    alert("Email is invalid");
    return;
    }

    if(phone is invalid){
    alert("phone is invalid");
    return;
    }

    var Check = confirm("Are you sure your entry is correct?");
    if (Check == false){
        return false;
    }
    else{ Submit Form };

}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. The only thing is that I have the validation process in my c# code and want to know if I can call the confirm pop-up from there.

Comment: I would validate on the client side if you can. If you have to involve the C# code you could use an ajax function to do the validation. It would be a better experience for the user because they wouldn't have to leave the page.  It does add complexity to the page though.